# Aggregating hourly data into daily aggregates

Tags: datetime, r, time, aggregate

I have an hourly weather data in the following format:

```
Date,DBT
01/01/2000 01:00,30
01/01/2000 02:00,31
01/01/2000 03:00,33
...
...
12/31/2000 23:00,25
```

What I need is a daily aggregate of max, min, ave like this:

```
Date,MaxDBT,MinDBT,AveDBT
01/01/2000,36,23,28
01/02/2000,34,22,29
01/03/2000,32,25,30
...
...
12/31/2000,35,9,20
```

How to do this in R?

Comment: next time, provide the data tables in a readible format, eg using dput() or giving runnable code that provides the data as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Having read the proposed answers, I wonder whether it cannot be done using base R only.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1) This can be done compactly using zoo:

```
L <- "Date,DBT
01/01/2000 01:00,30
01/01/2000 02:00,31
01/01/2000 03:00,33
12/31/2000 23:00,25"

library(zoo)
stat <- function(x) c(min = min(x), max = max(x), mean = mean(x))
z <- read.zoo(text = L, header = TRUE, sep = ",", format = "%m/%d/%Y", aggregate = stat)
```

This gives:

```
> z
           min max     mean
2000-01-01  30  33 31.33333
2000-12-31  25  25 25.00000
```

2) here is a solution that only uses core R:

```
DF <- read.csv(text = L)
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
ag <- aggregate(DBT ~ Date, DF, stat) # same stat as in zoo solution
```

The last line gives:

```
> ag
        Date  DBT.min  DBT.max DBT.mean
1 2000-01-01 30.00000 33.00000 31.33333
2 2000-12-31 25.00000 25.00000 25.00000
```

EDIT: (1) Since this first appeared the `text=` argument to `read.zoo` was added in the zoo package.
(2) minor improvements.

Comment: @Grothendieck : +1 I never realized you could just drop the hourly information by not specifying it in the as.Date().

Comment: Im looking at this from the phone but Id bet that the `aggregate` solution gives a list column which you cant really use for anything unless youll wrap the whole thing into `do.call(cbind.data.frame, aggregate...`

Comment: It produces a data.frame whose first column is `ag$Date. and whose second column is the matrix `ag$DBT`  whose columns are `"min"`, `"max"` and `"mean"`.  It readily converts to a zoo series using `read.zoo(ag)`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `strptime()`, `trunc()` and `ddply()` from the plyr package :

```
#Make the data
ZZ <- textConnection("Date,DBT
01/01/2000 01:00,30
01/01/2000 02:00,31
01/01/2000 03:00,33
12/31/2000 23:00,25")
dataframe <- read.csv(ZZ,header=T)
close(ZZ)

# Do the calculations
dataframe$Date <- strptime(dataframe$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
dataframe$day <- trunc(dataframe$Date,"day")

require(plyr)

ddply(dataframe,.(day),
      summarize,
      aveDBT=mean(DBT),
      maxDBT=max(DBT),
      minDBT=min(DBT)
)
```

gives

```
         day   aveDBT maxDBT minDBT
1 2000-01-01 31.33333     33     30
2 2000-12-31 25.00000     25     25
```

To clarify :

`strptime` converts the character to dates according to the format. To see how you can specify the format, see `?strptime`. `trunc` will then truncate these date-times to the specified unit, which is day in this case.

`ddply` will evaluate the function `summarize` within the dataframe after splitting it up according to `day`. everything after `summarize` are arguments that are passed to the function `summarize`.

Comment: Do you really need the wrapper around `summarize` ?

Comment: @Sacha : indeed, no need for that, thx for the correction. It's getting late here...

Answer (score 2):

There is also a nice package called `hydroTSM`. It uses `zoo` objects and can convert to other aggregates in time

The function in your case is `subdaily2daily`. You can choose if the aggregation should be based on min / max / mean...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

### 1. Timetk

If you have a data frame (or tibble) then the `summarize_by_time()` function from `timetk` can be used:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)

# Collect Data
text <- "Date,DBT
01/01/2000 01:00,30
01/01/2000 02:00,31
01/01/2000 03:00,33
12/31/2000 23:00,25"

df <- read_csv(text, col_types = cols(Date = col_datetime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")))
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Date                  DBT
#>   <dttm>              <dbl>
#> 1 2000-01-01 01:00:00    30
#> 2 2000-01-01 02:00:00    31
#> 3 2000-01-01 03:00:00    33
#> 4 2000-12-31 23:00:00    25

# Summarize
df %>%
  summarise_by_time(
    .date_var = Date, 
    .by       = "day",
    min       = min(DBT),
    max       = max(DBT),
    mean      = mean(DBT)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   Date                  min   max  mean
#>   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2000-01-01 00:00:00    30    33  31.3
#> 2 2000-12-31 00:00:00    25    25  25
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

### 2. Tidyquant

You can use the `tidyquant` package for this. The process is involves using the `tq_transmute` function to return a data frame that is modified using the xts aggregation function, `apply.daily`. We'll apply a custom `stat_fun`, which returns the min, max and mean. However, you can apply any vector function you'd like such as `quantile`.

```r
library(tidyquant)

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>                  Date   DBT
#>                <dttm> <dbl>
#> 1 2000-01-01 01:00:00    30
#> 2 2000-01-01 02:00:00    31
#> 3 2000-01-01 03:00:00    33
#> 4 2000-12-31 23:00:00    25

stat_fun <- function(x) c(min = min(x), max = max(x), mean = mean(x))

df %>%
    tq_transmute(select     = DBT,
                 mutate_fun = apply.daily,
                 FUN        = stat_fun)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#>                 Date   min   max     mean
#>                <dttm> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 2000-01-01 03:00:00    30    33 31.33333
#> 2 2000-12-31 23:00:00    25    25 25.00000
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what needs to be one if i need to aggregate at the hourly level

Comment: For hourly, you can use the `timetk::summarize_by_time(.by = "hour")`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have POSIXct time format, you can do this using as.POSIXct(time), all you need is cut and aggregate().

try this:

```
split_hour = cut(as.POSIXct(temp$time), breaks = "60 mins") # summrise given mins
temp$hour = split_hour # make hourly vaiable
ag = aggregate(. ~ hour, temp, mean)
```

In this case, temp is like this
temp

```
1  0.6 0.6 0.0 0.350 0.382 0.000 2020-04-13 18:30:42
2  0.0 0.5 0.5 0.000 0.304 0.292 2020-04-13 19:56:02
3  0.0 0.2 0.2 0.000 0.107 0.113 2020-04-13 20:09:10
4  0.6 0.0 0.6 0.356 0.000 0.376 2020-04-13 20:11:57
5  0.0 0.3 0.2 0.000 0.156 0.148 2020-04-13 20:12:07
6  0.0 0.4 0.4 0.000 0.218 0.210 2020-04-13 22:02:49
7  0.2 0.2 0.0 0.112 0.113 0.000 2020-04-13 22:31:43
8  0.3 0.0 0.3 0.155 0.000 0.168 2020-04-14 03:19:03
9  0.4 0.0 0.4 0.219 0.000 0.258 2020-04-14 03:55:58
10 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.118 0.000 0.000 2020-04-14 04:25:25
11 0.3 0.3 0.0 0.153 0.160 0.000 2020-04-14 05:38:20
12 0.0 0.7 0.8 0.000 0.436 0.493 2020-04-14 05:40:02
13 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.000 0.000 0.101 2020-04-14 05:40:44
14 0.3 0.0 0.3 0.195 0.000 0.198 2020-04-14 06:09:26
15 0.2 0.2 0.0 0.130 0.128 0.000 2020-04-14 06:17:15
16 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.144 0.000 0.000 2020-04-14 06:19:36
17 0.3 0.0 0.4 0.177 0.000 0.220 2020-04-14 06:23:43
18 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.110 0.000 0.000 2020-04-14 06:25:19
19 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.199 1.035 0.251 2020-04-14 07:05:24
20 0.2 0.2 0.0 0.125 0.107 0.000 2020-04-14 07:21:46
```

ag is like this

ag

```
1  2020-04-13 18:30:00 0.60000000 0.6000000 0.0000000 0.3500000 0.38200000 0.00000000
2  2020-04-13 19:30:00 0.15000000 0.2500000 0.3750000 0.0890000 0.14175000 0.23225000
3  2020-04-13 21:30:00 0.00000000 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.0000000 0.21800000 0.21000000
4  2020-04-13 22:30:00 0.20000000 0.2000000 0.0000000 0.1120000 0.11300000 0.00000000
5  2020-04-14 02:30:00 0.30000000 0.0000000 0.3000000 0.1550000 0.00000000 0.16800000
6  2020-04-14 03:30:00 0.30000000 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.1685000 0.00000000 0.12900000
7  2020-04-14 05:30:00 0.18750000 0.1500000 0.2125000 0.1136250 0.09050000 0.12650000
8  2020-04-14 06:30:00 0.10000000 0.1000000 0.0000000 0.6620000 0.57100000 0.12550000
9  2020-04-14 07:30:00 0.00000000 0.3000000 0.2000000 0.0000000 0.16200000 0.11800000
10 2020-04-14 19:30:00 0.20000000 0.3000000 0.0000000 0.1460000 0.19000000 0.00000000
11 2020-04-14 20:30:00 0.06666667 0.2000000 0.2666667 0.0380000 0.11766667 0.17366667
12 2020-04-14 22:30:00 0.20000000 0.3000000 0.0000000 0.1353333 0.18533333 0.00000000
13 2020-04-14 23:30:00 0.00000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.28000000 0.32100000
14 2020-04-15 01:30:00 0.25000000 0.2000000 0.4500000 0.1355000 0.11450000 0.26100000
```