# Aggregate stacked multivariate hourly data into daily maximum, and means in R with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, max, aggregate

I have searched various R aggregation questions here on stackoverflow (e.g [Aggregating hourly data into daily aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200437/aggregating-hourly-data-into-daily-aggregates)) but none  addresses multivariate table in long format.

My table is hourly table of observed and modeled values (for a whole year), for each site (up to eight) as shown below:

```
date    obs mod site
2017-01-01 00:00:00 1.2 -0.7    Carib
2017-01-01 01:00:00 3.1 -0.9    Carib
2017-01-01 02:00:00 2.1 -0.3    Carib
..
..
2017-02-17 10:00:00 2   1.5 Halley
2017-02-17 11:00:00 2.7 1.8 Halley
2017-02-17 12:00:00 3   2.2 Halley
..
..
2017-03-13 13:00:00 5.6 5.6 Yules
2017-03-13 14:00:00 6.5 5.0 Yules
2017-03-13 15:00:00 7.5 4.6 Yules
```

Below is the result I would like to have (excluding missing data)

```
date max_obs    max_mod mean_obs mean_mod  site
2017-01-01 -0.7 3.1 -0.9 0.9 Carib
2017-01-02 0.2 -1.5 -0.3 0.5 Carib
..
..
2017-02-17 2.2 1.5 1.1 0.8 Halley
2017-02-18 1.6 1.9 1.2 0.9 Halley
..
..
2017-03-13 5.6 5.2 4.7 5.0 Yules
2017-03-14 5.0 5.2 4.9 5.2 Yules
..
```

I imported my data as table, and tried daily averaging with `date <- as.Date(DT$date,"%Y-%m-%d")` but not getting what I want. Any help will  be appreciated.

Comment: If you give this a read it will help you format your question better and resulting in a faster/more accurate solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Tried formatting it while typing the question, but could n't

Comment: Thanks Alon for the edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean with the "table": whether you are using `data.table` package or just `read.table()` function of the base R. I'll give an answer which works for both approaches but is [suboptimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27511604/8465924) if you are using `data.table`.

The most convenient way to solve your problem is to use packages of the `tidyverse` family: `dplyr` for data manipulation and `lubridate` for transformation of the dates, like this

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

res_df <- obs_df %>%
    mutate(calend_day = as_date(date)) %>%
    group_by(calend_day, site) %>%
    summarize(
        max_obs = max(obs),
        max_mod = max(mod),
        mean_obs = mean(obs),
        mean_mod = mean(mod)
        ) %>%
    # set a desired order of columns
    select(calend_day, max_obs, max_mod, mean_obs, mean_mod, site)
```

Type of the `date` column is supposed to by a character, so `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` should be set when using `read.table()`.

Hope, it helps :)