# How to aggregate hourly data into daily values for several years

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data set with "UI" measurements every 4 hours for each day, for 7 years. I need to transform the hourly data into daily data, calculating the mean of every 4 hours for all the years.

The data set looks like this:

```
# A tsibble: 10,225 x 6 [6h] <UTC>
     Ano   Mes   Dia  Hora    UI    Date               
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dttm>             
 1  2012     1     1     0   37.9  2012-01-01 00:00:00
 2  2012     1     1     6    9.18 2012-01-01 06:00:00
 3  2012     1     1    12    1.18 2012-01-01 12:00:00
 4  2012     1     1    18   27.0  2012-01-01 18:00:00
 5  2012     1     2     0 -292.   2012-01-02 00:00:00
 6  2012     1     2     6   98.2  2012-01-02 06:00:00
 7  2012     1     2    12   95.9  2012-01-02 12:00:00
 8  2012     1     2    18    6.19 2012-01-02 18:00:00
 9  2012     1     3     0   -4.65 2012-01-03 00:00:00
10  2012     1     3     6   40.1  2012-01-03 06:00:00
# ... with 10,215 more rows
```

I used the function aggregate:

```
dados<-aggregate(dados2018$UI,by=list(dados2018$Dia),median)
```

But it gave me the median for each day for all the months and all the years together. I need only the daily median for all the days of every month, in every year.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200437/aggregating-hourly-data-into-daily-aggregates?rq=1

Comment: `aggregate(UI ~ Ano + Mes + Dia, dados2018, median)`.